# How to make close button stay top right of a native <dialog> (sticky/fixed not working)

Tags: css

In the below image, you can see the red close button is scrolling out of view (should always remain top right).
I thought no problem, I will fix it with `position: fixed` ... then it's positioned relative to the body, ok how about `position: sticky`, also did not work. Seems like only absolute position works within a dialog, so weird.

[image]

```js
LOREM.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum my latin is not so great. ".repeat(400);
DIALOG.showModal();
```

```css
#DIALOG {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

#CLOSE {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="DIALOG">
  <button id="CLOSE">X</button>
  <div id="LOREM"></div>
</dialog>
```

Update: Make it a modal type dialog

Answer (score 1):

Sticky is working. See this

```js
document.querySelector("#LOREM").innerText = "Lorem Ipsum my latin is not so great. ".repeat(400);
```

```css
#DIALOG {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

#CLOSE {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 95%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<dialog open id="DIALOG">
  <button id="CLOSE">X</button>
  <div id="LOREM"></div>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Sticky is working relative to the viewport, if the modal changes size, your close button is no longer in the right place, your left 95% positions it correctly only for your current screen

Comment: If you try resizing this here, close button also adjusts to the dialog size.

Comment: Okay can you make it positioned top right of the dialog? The dialog size can change.

Comment: Surprisingly, if you set the #DIALOG padding to 0, and posiiton the Close to `left:100%` it works. `right:0%` does not work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put one element on top of another why don't you wrap the two element in a wrapper and use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` in child elements.

Here is an example:

```js
LOREM.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum my latin is not so great.".repeat(400);
```

```css
#DIALOG {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

#CLOSE {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="CLOSE">X</button>
  <dialog open id="DIALOG">
    <div id="LOREM"></div>
  </dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works if it's not a modal type dialog, however I am using a modal type dialog (I originally tried to keep the question as simple as possible). Heres the changes:
1. Remove `open` attribute from dialog
2. Open it with `DIALOG.showModal();`